# Inconsistant OpenGL rendering bug with 3D objects

Tags: c++, opengl, game-engine

So I've been hammering away at my code for a while, trying to resolve this bug, with absolutely no progress being made.

Mostly due to how utterly random and unpredictable this bug is.

So this is how the scene works when everything is working fine

[image]

And when the bug kicks in

[image]

As you can see, the bug only prevents my cubemap skybox, model, and light source mesh from rendering, but the ortho projected 2d elements are just fine.

I've ruled out shaders, as even the simplest of shader programs still experience this problem. I use ASSIMP to load in mesh files and SOIL to load textures, but up until about a day ago they have worked flawlessly.

There is absolutely no pattern to when this happens, the only way to resolve it is to just keep restarting the program until the desired output appears. That is obviously not a good solution. I'm at a complete loss and need help, as opengl doesn't push out an error or anything. I don't know where to even begin looking for a solution. Could EBO's or frame buffers cause this? As I have started implementing those recently.

I have searched far and wide for anything that could be related to this, but I have come up with nothing so far.

TL;DR: 3D objects will not render only on some runs and work fine on others, possible issues with recently implemented framebuffers and EBOs.

Comment: You should absolutely be using tools like KHR_debug and the address sanitizer.  As written, how are we supposed to know how to help you?

Comment: Random bugs are usually due to uninitalized vars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

It turns out that my mouse look code in my Camera class was causing some odd issues where calculating the change in camera angles caused it to be set to an extraordinarily high negative value. Turning mouse look off permanently resolved the issue.